# Are there cases in which "empiric" and "empirical" are not interchangeable?

Tags: adjectives, nouns, suffixes

On [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) I found 3 instances of *empiric solution* and 4 instances of *empirical solution*.

What does this mean, if it means something—perhaps *empiric* and *empirical* are completely interchangeable? Or, does there exist some differences in usage?

Answer (score 6):

As an adjective, *empiric* means *empirical*.  It can additionally be used as a noun, while *empirical* cannot.  So as long as you're using it as an adjective, then yes, *empiric* and *empirical* are interchangeable.  (I think the *-ical* version usually sounds better, but that's just personal preference.)

Note that *empiric* was originally a noun only.  The suffix *-al* was added to make it into the adjective *empirical*, but *empiric* itself came to be used as an adjective as well.  Since this happened over four hundred years ago, and since both words have continued to be used with the same meaning, you can use whichever you like.

I should add, though, that *empirical* is more common in most contexts.  (This probably has something to do with why I think it "usually sounds better", as I wrote above.)

Comment: snail, +1; but may I ask you if the question title is grammatical? Italian people have some difficulties in usage of the word "interchange" and the phrase "each other".

Comment: I think it's missing the word *with* before *each other*.

Comment: snail, thank you, a lot. I'm going to edit the title.